# image not showing using iamgeurl?

Tags: angularjs

This is my code

```
  location: {
        address: 'Google Headquarters',
        city: 'Mountain View',
        province: 'CA'
    },
    imageUrl: "img/angularjs-logo.png",
    sessions: [
        {
            name: 'Directives Masterclass',
            creatorName: 'Bob Smith',
            duration: '1 hr',
            level: 'Advanced',
            abstract: 'In this sesison you will learn the ins and outs of directives!',
            upVoteCount: 0
        },
```

The image is not showing , this is the conroller.js, im using AngularJS v1.2.10.

```
  <div ng-controller="EventController" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px">
        <img ng-src="{{event.imageUrl}}" alt="{{event.name}}" />
```

Maybe there is difference ways to show it , i dont get a error. I saw a toturial online and it does it the same way.
can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add a bit more behaviour? How did you wrote your markup?

Comment: @maurizio , i have edit

Comment: I created a plunker to show you this: http://plnkr.co/edit/E88FmgpufuquV7XNGLQU?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are supposed to have is the event variable in the scope of your controller to make it work:

Your controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.event = { location: {
        address: 'Google Headquarters',
        city: 'Mountain View',
        province: 'CA'
    },
    title: "some title",
    imageUrl: "http://plnkr.co/img/plunker.png",
    sessions: [
        {
            name: 'Directives Masterclass',
            creatorName: 'Bob Smith',
            duration: '1 hr',
            level: 'Advanced',
            abstract: 'In this sesison you will learn the ins and outs of directives!',
            upVoteCount: 0
        },
    ]};


});
```

Your html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p><img ng-src="{{event.imageUrl}}" title="{{event.title}}" /></p>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks, so is the way i did it the OLD way? because of the tutorial i was watching it work , there is no difference on what i did